# How do I get multiple animations with a click, and then multiple different animations on the same element with a 2nd click alternating the animations?

Tags: c#, jquery, css, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to JQuery and JavaScript so forgive me if this is an easy fix, but I have been searching the internet and cannot find an answer. Lot's of questions with the same topic but none of the answers work. They are either outdated and suggest using .toggle() or they don't account for clicking on the same element.

With .toggle() being deprecated I cannot figure out how to do this with a click event instead of a hover. The hover gets messy and can be jumpy with so many cards but you can see the effect I want in the JSFiddle. Basically I want the first click to bring the card up, to the front, and then back down in front of all the other cards so you can see all the info on the card, and then the 2nd click to reverse that action by taking the card back up, push it to the back, and slide it down behind where it came from. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofdyc4b0/)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".UserCards").hover(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css({
            "margin-top": "-230px", "z-index": "1", "background-color": "#e8feff" });
        setTimeout(function () {
            $this.css("margin-top", "0px")
        }, 250);
    }, function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css({
            "margin-top": "-230px", "z-index": "0", "background-color": "white", "box-shadow": "8px -4px 11px -5px #888888"
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            $this.css("margin-top", "0px")
        }, 250);
    }
    );
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a neighbor it has been solved. see [JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ypexd57v/1/?fbclid=IwAR31OwFujwnbu65ASUEIcQgjWrTzlm2udf5tWo2svoEV8gt0N0JK7drRf4w)

```
.card {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 8px -4px 11px -5px #888888;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 5px -120px 5px;
    transition: margin 300ms;
    z-index: 0;
  }

.card.moveUp {
  margin-top: -125px;
  background-color: #e8feff;
  transition: margin 300ms;
  z-index: 0;
}

.card.pullForward {
  z-index: 1;
}

.card.moveDown {
  margin-top: 0;
  transition: margin 300ms;
}




$(document).ready(function() {
$("#CardContainer").on('click', '.card', function() {
const $card = $(this);
if($card.hasClass('moveDown')) {
    $card.removeClass('moveDown');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $card.removeClass('pullForward moveUp');
  }, 310);
} else {
    $card.addClass('moveUp');
  setTimeout(function () {
    $card.addClass('pullForward moveDown');
  }, 310);
}
});
});
```